# Proving inequality

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

I have been assigned a problem to solve in my probability class and I'm having a hard time starting it.

$\frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\leq \int^{\infty}_x e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}dt\leq \frac{1}{x} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

Any hints on where to begin would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the right-hand inequality, note that $$\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt < \int_x^\infty \frac tx e^{-t^2/2}\,dt.$$

Comment: The left inequality looks wrong. If $x\to 0^+$ the left-hand side blows up, but the middle term does not. Perhaps the $1/x$ factor in the left-hand side should not be there?

Answer (score -1):

hint :

$\int  e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}dt=\int -\dfrac{1}{t} de^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}=...$